# Silverlight Installation Got Corrupt

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I am facing the problem from 3 days and i think it all started when i installed Visual studio 2013 on my machine that already has VS2010 and VS2012.

Don't remember the exact steps after that but one thing is confirm it happened after vs2013 installation.

Previously it showed some kind of error in Microsoft.Expression. on designer while loading the windows phone page and it happened on all of the pages of all projects.

It vs2012 didn't recognize even the  tags  etc.

I uninstalled VS2013 and vs2012, installed vs2012 again bt still no remedy. Now when i open vs and try to create even a new windows phone project it shwos following

below is the image of error i see every time i try to open my existing windows phone projects.

[image]

Below are the last entries in the file mentioned in the image above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you upgraded to Windows 8.1. That upgrade has fracked most people's Silverlight development environment. I am working through that issue myself and if you upgraded to 8.1, you may want to search for solutions for that.

Here's a link with further information:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/960abca1-5f10-4608-ad72-93ecef6e70a7/windows-81-killed-my-silverlight-development-environment?forum=silverlightdevtools

I did just the uninstall and install of the developer exe and that solved my problems.

Hope that helps!